# Changing parts of a code in a for loop

Tags: java, android

I have this strings_xml file:

```
<resources>
<string name="a1">Maximum Arka Plan Sayısına Ulaştınız</string>
<string name="a2">Minimum Arka Plan Sayısına Ulaştınız</string>
<string name="a3">Başarıyla Arka Planı Ayarladınız</string>
<string name="a4">Arka plan orijinale döndürüldü</string>
<string name="a5">Arka plan orijinale döndürüldü</string>
<string name="a6">Arka plan orijinale döndürüldü</string>
                                .
                                .
                                .
```

I want to add all strings into a ArrayList so I need to do this:

```
alltoast.add(c.getString(R.string.a1));
alltoast.add(c.getString(R.string.a2));
alltoast.add(c.getString(R.string.a3));
alltoast.add(c.getString(R.string.a4));
                .
                .
                .
```

So I am thinking about a for loop where I change only "1" , "2" parts of the code something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<50; i++ ){
alltoast.add(c.getString(R.string.a$i));

}
```

(alltoast is the name of the ArrayList , c is the context of the method)

Comment: Use string-array in resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your strings in a [String array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray). Then you can access the elements by index in the loop.

> EXAMPLE: XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <string-array name="planets_array">
>         <item>Mercury</item>
>         <item>Venus</item>
>         <item>Earth</item>
>         <item>Mars</item>
>     </string-array>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> This application code retrieves a string array:
>
> ```
> Resources res = getResources();
> String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
> ```

But in fact, you wouldn't need a loop:

```
 alltoast.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));
```

Comment: @Cem this is the way .Why make it so complex ?